# Is there a way to pass parameter into XPath NpgsqlCommand?

Tags: sql, postgresql, xpath, parameters, npgsql

In SQL Server I can use `sql:variable`:

```
string sql = "select * from mytable where xml_column.exist('//Tag[text()=sql:variable(\"@value\")]') = 1";
```

I was trying to find similar way to pass parameter into NpgsqlCommand. This one for example does not fail but also does not return any data:

```
string sql = "select * from mytable where xmlexists('//Tag[text()=\"@value\"]' PASSING BY REF xml_column) = true";
```

Is there any way of doing it?
Thanks!

Here is a code snippet:

```
string connstr = "PORT=5432;DATABASE=mydb;HOST=myhost;USER ID=myuser;PASSWORD=mypassword";
using (NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connstr))
{
    connection.Open();

    string sql = "select xml_column from mytable where xmlexists('//Tag[text()=\"@value\"]' PASSING BY REF xml_column) = true";
    using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", "my value");
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                reader[0].Dump();
            }
        }
    }

    connection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cross-posted on github, see answer there: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/2946

Comment: I tried the 3rd suggestion, with quote_literal function and the server side concatenation, but could not make it work, getting:

PostgresException 
42601: syntax error at or near "||"